# Prove 2017 points in a plane cannot form 2017 triangles with the largest area

Tags: combinatorics, plane-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

I haven’t got an idea about this problem . Could someone  help me?

Suppose 2017 points in a plane are given such that no three points are colinear. Among the triangles formed by any three of these 2017 points, those triangles having the largest area are said to be good. Prove that there cannot be more than 2017 good triangles.

Comment: where did you find this problem? In an exam?

Comment: An interesting problem. People eager to press the close button should think again.

Comment: Wonder if this implies that the $2017$ points be equally spaced on a circle.

Comment: According to [this](https://www.math.ust.hk/excalibur/v21_n3_20180108.pdf), it's from the 2017 Hong Kong Math Olympiad. The [AOPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c36h1554011_chkmo_p4) posting has some discussion.

Comment: AOPS post failed so i want find good solution